# Simple Java Error

Tags: java, coding-style

This is a factorial program in java, its not working please let me know the errors. Thanks!

```
class Fact {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      int i=5,num=1;

      while(i>1) {
         num=num*i;
      }
      i--;

      System.out.println("Value: " + num);      
   }
}
```

Comment: You are decrementing `i` outside the while loop. Move it to inside the while loop. Currently it enters a infinite loop.

Comment: Using a logical and consistent way of indenting code blocks, helps the reader to understand the flow of a program.  That code uses indentation which is **anything but** logical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You decrease the variable `i` outside of the `while` loop when it's supposed to be inside of it.

```
  while(i>1)
  {
     num=num*i;
  }
  i--;
```

Should be:

```
  while(i>1)
  {
     num=num*i;
     i--;
  }
```

What your current code says is that `while *i* is greater than 1 do your multiplication`. The problem is that **i** will always be greater then 1 since you never substract from it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use decrement of i inside loop
2. Add check for negative value (you should also process 0 value)

Comment: About your second point: That would depend on how many times (s)he would like to iterate and since (s)he hasn't specified that we don't know if it's supposed to be 4 or 5 times ;)

Comment: I mean you should process smth like fact(-2), fact(0) etc.

Comment: That would be true if was to be a method to be used in real life, I have doubts that this isn't the case since it's in the main-method :) But good point